# Finding $P(X+Y=2)$ of a joint $pmf$ $p_{X,Y}(x, y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> $X$ and $Y$ have joint $pmf$
>
> $$p_{X,Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases} {\frac{2^{x+y}e^{-4}}{x!y!}} &
>  \text{$x\in{\{0,1,2,...}\}, y\in{\{0,1,2,...,}\}$} \\  {0} &
>  \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> What is the value of $P(X+Y= 2)$?

I have that $X+Y=2$ can only be true when $(x,y)=(2,0),(0,2)$, or $(1,1)$. Then would I just sum $\frac{2^{x+y}e^{-4}}{x!y!}$ for each of these combinations? Which would give,

$$\frac{2^{2+0}e^{-4}}{2!0!}+\frac{2^{0+2}e^{-4}}{0!2!}+\frac{2^{1+1}e^{-4}}{1!1!}=.1465$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the approach is correct.

$$\frac{2^{2+0}e^{-4}}{2!0!}+\frac{2^{0+2}e^{-4}}{0!2!}+\frac{2^{1+1}e^{-4}}{1!1!}=\left(\frac42+\frac{4}{2}+4 \right)\exp(-4)=.1465$$

Comment: Great thanks! I'm fairly new to $pmf$'s so I just wanted to be sure I did it correctly.